# Flutter column doesn't expand

Tags: dart, flutter

I am a complete newbie in Flutter, but I already like it. 
The question is: 
why is the column not expanding to the full height?

[code is on gist.github](https://gist.github.com/kitttn/bac291c4856cabb1114aefe929c0ac90)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please include the code in your question, not just a link to it.

Answer (score 45):

Using `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` works for me:

```
   Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
          Text("Some title"),
          Text("Address"),
          Text("Description")
      ],
   ),
```

Comment: CrossAxisAlignment on columns refers to the horizontal width. If you set CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, it will stretch left to right and not up to down.

Comment: I get this: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out

Comment: Does not work well if you have a CircularProgressIndicator inside the column.

Answer (score 35):

A [Column](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) widget is flexible - it will try to take up as much space as it needs but no more. If you want it to take up all availible space, then wrap it in an [Expanded](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget.

```
createChildren() {
  return [
    Image.network(
      testImg,
      height: imageSize,
      width: imageSize,
    ),
    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0)),
    Expanded(child:
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          boldText("Some title"),
          Text("Address"),
          Text("Description")
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ];
}
```

Comment: This only works if the `Column` is inside another `Flex` widget, as `Expanded` can only be placed inside a `Flex` widget.

Answer (score 9):

Wrapping the column with a row with  `MainAxisSize.max`

```
Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              _someWidget(),
              _someWidget(),
              _someWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. To get it to work, I had to wrap the nested column within an Expanded. `mainAxisSize` wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your layout I assume that your `Column` is nested inside a `Row`. Wrap your `Row` with `IntrinsicHeight` and your `Column` will automatically expand its height to be the same as the `Row`'s tallest child:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(width: 40, height: 40, color: Colors.blue),
                    // tallest child
                    Container(width: 40, height: 60, color: Colors.blue),
                    // height will be 60
                    Column(
                      ...
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use flex=1 inside Column, here you can see example

```
children: [
    MyWidget(),
    Expanded(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
    MyWidget(),
  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `Column` inside an infinite width `SizedBox`.

```
SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [ ... ]
  )
)
```

The above code snippet will place the children at the center of the `SizedBox`. It'll work especially well if you want to use a `Column` as the body of your `Scaffold`. In that case children will show up at the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The code linked in the question is no longer available, so I can't give you a full working example for your case. However, one thing that will likely work is using `mainAxisAlignment` as follows:

```dart
   Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
          Text("Some title"),
          Text("Address"),
          Text("Description")
      ],
   ),
```

(`mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` is actually the default value, butthis only works if you do not set it to `MainAxisSize.min`, so I included it here.)

Setting `mainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround` or `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` will also expand the column, but spacing between/around children will be handled differently. Try it out and see which you like best!

This will cause the column to take all the space it can - if it still doesn't expand then that is due to its parent widget, and we can no longer access the code so I can't speak to that.